# Editor in Visual Studio does not recognize reference to constant with ${} in url in node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, express, axios

I am following [instructions from hubspot](https://app.hubspot.com/academy/8548907/tracks/71/592/2965?ruid=12096848) in writing a simple script in node.js that calls there API using an API key. The example also makes use of express and axios. I am using VS code.

When I reference the api key saved as a constant, the editor does not recognize it as a reference to the earlier saved constant.

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = express ();

const API_KEY_TEST_PORTAL = "066e6549-7853-4914-92b0-9ad61966be4c"

app.get('/contacts', async (req, res) => {
    const contacts = 'https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/lists/all/contacts/recent?hapikey=${API_KEY_TEST_PORTAL}';
```

You can find screenshots of the example and my own code below. The only difference I find between the two is that my '$' sign is larger than the example, not sure what that means. When I copy out the `${API_KEY_TEST_PORTAL}` into another section of the script the editor does recognize the connection to the constant `const API_KEY_TEST_PORTAL = "066e6549-7853-4914-92b0-9ad61966be4c"`

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

[Screenshot of the instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fzNa.png)

[Screenshot of my VS editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDH8M.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `${something}` syntax is known as [*string interpolation* or *template literals*.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) You use backticks, not quotation marks, to delimit strings for interpolation.

Use this sort of thing.

```
   const val = `https://what/ever/recent?hapikey=${API_KEY_TEST_PORTAL}`;
```

Comment: Thanks that was an easy fix. Appreciate the help!